# Octave installation error on Mac - vecLibFort error

Tags: macos, octave

I am trying to install Octave by following the instructions given in the wiki - http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X, now I am getting the error below not sure what it is and how to go about solving it.

```
==> Installing dependencies for octave: veclibfort, arpack, fftw, glpk, c
==> Installing octave dependency: veclibfort
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading https://github.com/mcg1969/vecLibFort/archive/0.3.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/veclibfort-0.3.0.tar.gz
==> make all
1 error generated.
make: *** [libvecLibFortI.dylib] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make: *** [vecLibFort.o] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/homebrew):
  https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science/issues
```

Comment: brew should have downloaded and installed all dependencies required for the build of Octave and it failed. The last message suggests that you report this bug to `homebrew-science`. Have you done that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just installed Octave using the binary installer from source forge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20MacOSX%20Binary/